Polyfill.io Issue for Google Maps Platform users
Today i got a message from google cloud platoform, its mentioned a "Notification Title: [Security Alert]: Polyfill.io Issue for Google Maps Platform users" how can we resolve the issue. website is running in a wordpress

We got the same message, not sure how to resolve though.

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview for more info

This guide on here should help or use Cloudflare's alternative

Were you ever able to figure out what other libraries besides Polyfill.io are affected by this issue? The text of the notification says "specific third-party libraries INCLUDING polyfill.io" and recomments to check if you are using ANY of the compromised libraries but then doesn't proceed to offer a list of such libraries. Does anybody know?
